# Modeling a Time to Digital Converter in Verilog-AMS

Tags: verilog, modeling

I'm trying to write a TDC (Time to Digital Converter) model in Verilog AMS. I'm really new at the AMS part of Verilog.

The problem I'm running into is in assigning the final state of the TDC to the outputs. Below I present the code. I get "Expecting a scalar expression" on the line within the generate.

```
module TDC_model #(
parameter integer N_delays    = 50,
parameter Time_delay  = 20p,
parameter Vdd         = 1.8   // Positive power supply V
) (
input TDC_Start_i,
input TDC_Stop_i,
// input TDC_CLK_i,
input TDC_Rst_p_i,

output TDC_therm_o
);

electrical [N_delays - 1: 0] TDC_therm_o;
electrical TDC_Start_i, TDC_Stop_i, TDC_Rst_p_i;
integer i;
real vmid;

real delay_reg[0: N_delays - 1];
real delay_chain[0: N_delays - 1];

analog begin
//Initialize parameters
@(initial_step) begin
  vmid=(Vdd)/2.0;     // Midrail Voltage
  for(i=0; i< N_delays; i=i+1) begin
    delay_chain[i] = 0;
  end
end

//Delay chain delays propagates the signal
@(timer(0, Time_delay)) begin
for(i=1; i < N_delays; i=i+1) begin
  delay_chain[N_delays - i] = delay_chain[N_delays - i-1];
end

delay_chain[0] = V(TDC_Start_i); // Beginning of the delay chain
end

// At Stop threshold crossing, buffer the TDC status
@(cross(V(TDC_Stop_i) - vmid, +1)) begin 
  for(i=0; i< N_delays; i=i+1) begin
    delay_reg[i] = (delay_chain[i] >= vmid);      
  end
end

generate i (50 - 1, 0) begin
  V(TDC_therm_o) <+ transition(delay_reg[i],0 , 2p, 2p);
end

end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite embarrassingly, I left an [i] for the output within the generate block, which should be:

```
generate i (50 - 1, 0) begin
  V(TDC_therm_o[i]) <+ transition(delay_reg[i],0 , 2p, 2p);
end
```

With that, the model works well.